# Create buttons from folders in the resource folder iOS Unity

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine, directory

I'm trying to figure out how I get all my folders in the resources folder as buttons in iOS.
I got it working on windows with this code:

```
string path = Application.dataPath + "/Resources/Prefabs/Models/";
foreach (string s in Directory.GetDirectories(path))
{
    projects.Add(s.Remove(0, path.Length));
}

foreach (string result in projects)
{
    buttonResult = Instantiate(buttonProjectPrefab).GetComponent<Button>();
    buttonResult.transform.SetParent(GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Level").transform);
    buttonResult.GetComponent<RectTransform>().localScale = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);
    buttonResult.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(delegate { CreateModelButtons(); });
    buttonResult.name = result;
    buttonResult.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = result;
}
```

So now I'm trying to figure out how to do this for iOS. 
I know Unity encodes the files, soo what I used won't be possible.

What should I do to get all the folders in my resource folder to create them as button on iOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code only worked in the Editor. So instead I created a work around. 
I created an empty gameobject in the resource folder. 
So instead of using folders to get the buttons, I use the gameobjects to created buttons.

I used the code the same way as my question, but this time it works outside the Editor